# Load YouTube Iframe API using XHR (AngularJS' $http) and CORS

Tags: angularjs, api, youtube, xmlhttprequest, cors

I want to load the YouTube Iframe API ( https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api ) using AngularJS' $http, but it seems that YouTube doesn't allow CORS requests.

The reason I want to load this API using XHR is that I have a fairly complex logic for API loading in my app, and I want to test it using $httpBackend. And if I load the script using a  tag created from JS, I can't find any way of mocking it, and also it will actually execute the request each time I run the tests, which is not cool.

My other option is to create a local proxy, but I would like to avoid that at the current moment.

So, does anyone know any way of loading the YouTube Iframe API with XHR? Maybe setting an origin parameter to the request or something. Or maybe it already works but I'm missing something.